# How come it says 'no items found' when I expand a database in the 'Database Expert' in Crystal Reports?

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I work on a remote desktop server when accessing Crystal Reports.  I can open .rpt files but whenever I try to add a table, I get an error saying 'Data Object cannot be opened/accessed Details: cannot open file' then it says 'no items found.' Is this a permissions issue or is there something I have to do in order to view the tables in a database and the attributes in those tables?

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a database connection. Crystal reports does not know where to find the data.

For example, if you are on a Windows machine, you need to run ODBC Data Source Administrator and add the database connection to your machine. Then you can select it from within Crystal and add your table or SP to the report.

Comment: Well even when I try to set the datasource location, the DDF directory that would in theory show CR where to find the data on my system, it returns and error saying that certain tables could not be replaced, so then I try to open that directory i am trying to update to and i get the same error as the one in my original post.